# divide non sequential set of numbers into certain groups and return as rows in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database column with non sequential numbers. Say 1 3 5 8 13 15 16 17 20 23 34 54 68. I want to divide them into groups of 3 numbers each(dividing factor is 3 for equal ranges).How can I get the below range values?

[image]

Comment: Divide "into three groups"? Your own sample shows four rows in the output. Did you rather mean "into groups of three numbers each"? That makes more sense - but your fourth row, from 23 to 68, includes four values, not three (23, 34, 54, 68). Or is the requirement to include the final numbers in the last group, if the number of numbers is not divisible by three? (So that the last group may include three, four or five numbers, rather than having a last group with one or two numbers?)

Comment: Tip: use `ntile() over()`.

Comment: I mean groups of 3 numbers each and the final numbers in the last group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is.

In the WITH clause, I create the test data. Don't worry if you don't understand what it does; it simply creates a view INPUTS with a single column COL with the values you offered for testing. The actual query (the solution) begins after the WITH clause. To test it, remove everything up to the commented line about selecting from INPUTS.

```
with
  inputs(col) as (
    select column_value 
    from   sys.odcinumberlist(1,3,5,8,13,15,16,17,20,23,34,54,68)
  )
-- select * from inputs; */
select   row_num, min(col) as start_range, max(col) as end_range
from     (
           select col
                , least( ceil(row_number() over (order by col)/3), 
                         trunc(count(*) over () / 3)
                       ) as row_num
           from   inputs
         )
group by row_num
order by row_num
;

   ROW_NUM START_RANGE  END_RANGE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1           1          5
         2           8         15
         3          16         20
         4          23         68
```